# How to find the index of all letters in a user inputted string

Tags: python

This is the assignment:
Write a program that gets a single word from the user. For each letter in the word, print the index of that letter in the string 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' (e.g., 'A' would print 0, 'z' would print 51). Print all the indices on one line, separated by spaces.

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

word = input('Type a word: ')

for ind in word:
    answer = ind.index(alphabet[0,-1])
    print(answer)
```

My code does not run. It says "TypeError: string indices must be integers". 0 and -1 are both integers, and they indicate the first and last positions of a given string. I don't understand why this is not running properly. The code should take alphabet at position 0, see that there is no matching value in word, and then move on to the next one until it reaches the first character's position in the typed string. It should then print out that number, and keep going. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you mean by `alphabet[0,-1]`?

Comment: What your code says is "take each `ind`, find the character in `ind` at `alphabet[0,1]`, and print the result.  Even as I type that, it makes no sense.

Comment: as a side note - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html, you can use `string.ascii_letters`

Comment: alphabet from position 0 (the beginning) to position -1 (the end). Is that not right?

Comment: Your problem is at `ind.index`.

Comment: I think You mean `alphabet.index(ind)` instead of weird `ind.index(alphabet[0,-1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `index` the wrong way.  You need to swap the arguments:

```
answer = alphabet.index(ind)
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything runs perfectly now.

Comment: When you can, remember to "accept" an answer; this allows SO to neatly retire the question.

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes. I created a new account, and there is a time period before I have that ability. But I will for sure once the timer is up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meaning to be following a pattern like this.  Get a each character from the input word and find the index in alphabet where the character occurs.

```
answer = []
for char in word:
    answer += [alphabet.index(char)]
```

You can further simplify with a list comprehension

```
answer = [alphabet.index(char) for char in word]
```

Comment: you may need to handle missing values in the alphabet, perhaps return some special value instead.  Something like this would do `i = alphabet.index(char) if char in alphabet else None`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use ASCII codes using the `ord()` function,

```
word = input("word:")
for i in range(len(word)):
    print(ord(word[i:i+1]), end="")
```

This will give you a number output from a string and its not just limited to the alphabet